# 1D CNN keras wrong shape

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, shapes

I'm trying to fit a 1D CNN to my data. The data consists of MEL frequencies and have the following characteristics:

```
X_train.shape = (68251, 99)
y_train_hot.shape = (68251, 35)<-- one hot encoding with 35 output classes
```

When I try to train the model I'm getting this value error for the code below:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_5_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (68251, 99)


#hyperparameters
input_dimension = 68251
learning_rate = 0.0025
momentum = 0.85
hidden_initializer = random_uniform(seed=1)
dropout_rate = 0.2
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, input_shape=X_train.shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=16, filter_length=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=input_dimension, kernel_initializer=hidden_initializer, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer=hidden_initializer, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer=hidden_initializer, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train_hot, epochs=5, batch_size=128)
predictions = model.predict_proba(X_test)

ans = pd.DataFrame(predictions)
ans = ans[0]
```

And when I reshape the X_train and X_test to (68251, 99, 1) and (17063, 99, 1) respectively, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_7: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT
I actually compiled your model this time and found a few issues and corrected them:

```
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, input_shape=(99, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=16, filter_length=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(35, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train_hot, epochs=5, batch_size=128)
```

Your output was 2 and should be 35 as you have 35 output classes, your first Dense does not need input_dim as the shape will be inferred by the previous layer, and the input shape was wrong.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it still raises this error:
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Comment: oh sorry.. it does not expect the batch size. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, input_shape=X_train.shape, activation='relu'))
```

to

```
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, input_shape=(99,), activation='relu'))
```

and pass `X_train` to `fit` function without reshaping

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Running the model after changing as instructed gives me the following error:
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_11: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2